# How to Specify outgoing HELO with sendmail?

Tags: linux, email, sendmail

How do you specify the FQDN (Host and Domain Name) that a mail server presents itself as in HELO/EHLO when sending outgoing email with sendmail?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I added the following in sendmail.mc:

```
define(`confDOMAIN_NAME', `mail.foo.com')dnl
```

and then:

```
m4 sendmail.mc > sendmail.cf
service sendmail restart
```

I also verified that this worked with the email verifier service at http://www.port25.com/domainkeys/ (auth-results@verifier.port25.com). Neat service, you send it an email and it replies to the from header with information about your SPF, Domain Keys, etc...

Comment: Word of caution (perhaps common sense but I'll mention it anyway).  The value for `confDOMAIN_NAME` should NOT be an email domain.  Setting it to that will cause sendmail to reject messages because it thinks the mailboxes are (or should be) local.

Comment: This is not directly related to the question, but for anyone that arrives here looking for info on how to prevent your `foo.localdomain` from showing up in email headers, try using the `MASQUERADE` functions to ensure your sent mail doesn't contain a local machine name in the headers. I got that from here (lines must be entered before any `MAILER` entries) https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/sendmail-masquerading-configuration-howto.html

Comment: mail.foo.com is it our domain name?

Answer (score 10):

For completeness - one can also use

```
define(confHELO_NAME,`something.not.the.same.as.the.domain.name')
```

if one needs more absolute control (e.g. in a freeb-bsd jail it may be
desirable to have the confDOMAIN_NAME and MASQUERADE_AS set very different
than the HELO/EHLO names.

Dw.

Answer (score 0):

```
define(`confSMTP_LOGIN_MSG', `$j; $b')dnl
```

Also configure `/etc/hosts` file like below

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx           server server.yourdomain.com server
127.0.0.1                 server server.yourdomain.com server
```