# Spam avoidance issue

Tags: email-server, spam, smtp-headers

I'm working on a project right now that sends email as confirmation of purchase.  Some emails are still being received as spam.  I have signed the domain up for google apps for business & am using the PHPMailer code base (that is used for sugarCRM, drupal etc..) to send email via googles servers using smtps.  I realize that the body content of the message itself could be responsible..

However what I'm having a hard time understanding is the headers.  The domain ourgreatmovie.com shows up in numerous parts of the header.  This was originally the domain we were using until we changed to `turnofthiscentury.com`.  I thought it might have been due to the reverse DNS pointer that I had setup for the old domain - however I've had my hosting provider change this to the new domain & have verified the change.

Furthermore, I've checked `/etc/hosts file`; nothing there - same for `/etc/sysconfig/network` (CentOS 6); not sure anymore where this domain is coming from; sample copy of headers received at destination are below: Thanks in advance!

```
Received: by 10.205.75.199 with SMTP id zb7csp33558bkb; Thu, 29 Aug 2013 10:03:53 -0700 (PDT)
Received: from ourgreatmovie.com (turnofthiscentury.com. [199.103.57.26]) by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id mc6si19213371icc.79.1969.12.31.16.00.00 (version=TLSv1 cipher=RC4-SHA bits=128/128); Thu, 29 Aug 2013 10:03:52 -0700 (PDT)
Received: from ourgreatmovie.com (localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1]) by ourgreatmovie.com (8.13.8/8.13.8) with ESMTP id r7TCAYLw020926 for <reeceg@tbadigital.com>; Thu, 29 Aug 2013 08:10:34 -0400
Received: (from apache@localhost) by ourgreatmovie.com (8.13.8/8.13.8/Submit) id r7TCAYgg020925; Thu, 29 Aug 2013 08:10:34 -0400
X-Received: by 10.43.53.144 with SMTP id vq16mr1714222icb.41.1377795832986; Thu, 29 Aug 2013 10:03:52 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <apache@ourgreatmovie.com>
Received-Spf: neutral (google.com: 199.103.57.26 is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of apache@ourgreatmovie.com) client-ip=199.103.57.26;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=neutral (google.com: 199.103.57.26 is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of apache@ourgreatmovie.com) smtp.mail=apache@ourgreatmovie.com
X-Php-Originating-Script: 0:class.phpmailer.php
Message-Id: <462bedcaa876c16c2cd449a0aef4c23a@turnofthiscentury.com>
X-Priority: 3
X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.6 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/)
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it's what the mail server program is sending as it's HELO/EHLO.

Check this setting in your mail system: `smtp.mail=apache@ourgreatmovie.com` as well as any settings for how the server identifies itself during SMTP setup/communication.

Check these 2 links for reference:

[How to Specify outgoing HELO with sendmail?](https://serverfault.com/questions/205271/how-to-specify-outgoing-helo-with-sendmail)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5672651/change-helo-host-name-when-sending-email

Comment: Thanks, this would have taken me some time to figure out on my own.