# Server on blacklist

Tags: debian-wheezy

I have a Debian Wheezy server with several websites with separate domains. Some of these websites uses Wordpress and in turn uses PHP's mail function to send mail.

I installed "sendmail" to be able for the server to send mail from PHP. We use Google Apps for our customers, so no need to setup a regular mail server.

Now the server is blacklisted at www.spamhaus.org and get this message:

```
This IP address is HELO'ing as "localhost.localdomain" which violates the relevant standards (specifically: RFC5321).
```

I have tried to follow the instructions on these websites with no luck:
http://www.cardiothink.com/downloads/README.spamhaus-and-blocked-email.html
http://centosbeginer.wordpress.com/2011/07/12/how-to-remove-ip-in-cbl-spamhaus/

Can you please help me figure out how to configure the server?

**File: /etc/hosts**

```
# nameserver config
# IPv4
127.0.0.1 somedomain.dk
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx server.somedomain.dk bigby
#
# IPv6
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
xxxx::0 ip6-localnet
xxxx::0 ip6-mcastprefix
xxxx::1 ip6-allnodes
xxxx::2 ip6-allrouters
xxxx::3 ip6-allhosts
xxxx:xxx:xxx:xxxx::2  Debian-76-wheezy-64-minimal
```

**File: /etc/hostname**

```
bigby
```

somedomain.dk is a made up domain. In reality another domain name I have on this server along with other domains.

bigby is also a made up name. It is also something else in reality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're sending out a HELO with the wrong name.

Try the solution used for the following post:
[How to Specify outgoing HELO with sendmail?](https://serverfault.com/questions/205271/how-to-specify-outgoing-helo-with-sendmail)

If this doesn't help, can you provide more information about your sendmail configuration?

Comment: Seems to work so far. used "telnet localhost 25" and then "ehlo localhost". Seems right. Have delisted at spamhaus and now I will see if it works. Will get back as soon as I know.